# MVC-style model binding in WCF?

Tags: wcf, model-view-controller, model-binding

I want to bind POSTed form values to parameters in my WCF operation in the same way that ASP.Net MVC allows me to do.

So, for example if my form has "customer.Name" and "customer.Age" parameters, I want to make a standard HTML POST to a named endpoint/operation that takes a customer parameter and have it instantiated and populated like MVC can do...

It looks like I can use WebInvoke and its UriTemplate property to map simple parameters - does anyone know if a more MVC-like model-binding way is possible?

Thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will give me what I want:

http://wcfrestcontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Url%20Form%20Encoded%20Formatter%20Overview&referringTitle=De/serialization%20Overview

Answer (score 0):

The Model Binder in ASP.NET MVC is open source, permissive.  Potentially, you can co-opt it to perform your model binding for you.